# How to get Intellisense in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8 metro apps

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In Visual Studio 2012, Intellisense is not working in XAML files. How can I get it to work?

Comment: Doesn't work or it's limited?

Comment: actually i saw in microsoft's blog that it works but we need to make some changes.can u tell me those changes?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. It works for me just fine in Release Preview. You can force it to pop up using Ctrl+Space. If that doesn't work for you, your environment is damaged. Try repairing or reinstalling.